# JSON Error on clientside when sending ResponseEntity from serverside after post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest, spring-web

I have an angular/spring boot webapp. When I send a create user postrequest the angular clientside app isn't able to read the body of the response entity that I send back after the operation. The error is:

```
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "User successfully created."}
```

I know that this is caused because the body content isn't in JSON format. But the error persists even when I add `produces = "application/json"` as an attribute to the `@PostMapping` annotation.

Heres the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/user")
public class UserController {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @PostMapping(path = "/create", produces = "application/json")
    private ResponseEntity<String> createNewUser(@RequestBody UserCreateDTO newUser) {
        logger.info("name is: " + newUser.getUserName());
        Status status = userService.createUser(newUser);
        return ResponseEntity.status(status.isSuccess() ?
                HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(status.getInfo());
    }
```

What should I do to solve this problem? I think it has something to do with the use of ResponseEntity. I could just send the status DTO object that I've made back instead, but I want to be able to manipulate the httpStatus code that is being sent back too, so that's why I want to use the ResponseEntity instead.

Comment: when i look at the Reponse section of chrome dev tools i can see that the response is in plain tekst not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're returning a string literal instead of a json object. The returning object when converted to json should be like

```
{
  "status": "user created successfully"
}
```

try returning your full `status` object instead of `status.getInfo()` then your return object should look something like:

```
{
   "info": "user created successfully"
}
```

and you can call `status.info` within your javascript to reference the return

and will have to change your return type to `RepsonseEntity<Status>`

Answer (score 0):

In fact yes you are using `ResponseEntity` but with a `String` as body, because you are using:

```
.body(status.getInfo());
```

You need to specify an object in the body, you can create a POJO that will hold the message for you, wraps the `status.getInfo()` String, and it will be read as JSON.

The message POJO class:

```
public class MessageObject {
    private String message;
    //Constructors, getter and setter
}
```

Your return code would be:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(status.isSuccess() ?
                HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new MessageObject(status.getInfo()));
```

Comment: responseBody is already included thanks to convenience annotation @RestController